# Why does this regex only match once?

Tags: java, regex

I have strings which look like this:

```
"Mo 13:00 - 14:00, Di 15:00-19:00, Montag - Dienstag 18:00-23:00 Montag bis Samstag 03:00 bis 10:00"
```

and i want to create substrings like this:

```
"Mo 13:00 - 14:00", "Di 15:00-19:00", "Montag - Dienstag 18:00-23:00"...
```

if have now created this pattern:

```
"([a-zA-Z\\s]*\\d\\d[:]\\d\\d\\s\\S*\\s\\d\\d[:]\\d\\d)"
```

but with Matcher.find() i only get one result:`"Mo 13:00 - 14:00"`

here is a sample code in case i made a silly mistake:

```
String xy = "Mo 13:00 - 14:00, Di 15:00-19:00, Montag - Dienstag 18:00-23:00 Montag bis      Samstag 03:00 bis 10:00";
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z\\s]*\\d\\d[:]\\d\\d\\s\\S*\\s\\d\\d[:]\\d\\d)");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xy);
while(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Tried using `.split(",")` instead?

Comment: Clearly, you should be using `String#split` and put an end to this regex madness.

Comment: @Marko if all the segments were separated by commas then I'd agree with you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex pattern like this:

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s-]*\\d\\d[:]\\d\\d\\s*\\S*?\\s*\\d\\d[:]\\d\\d)`
 \______/\___________/\_____________/\__/     \__/\_____________/
    |          |           ##:##       |_______|       ##:##
    |          |                           |
start with   accepts any number of       account for 
a letter     letters, spaces or "-"      optional spaces
             (Required for dates like:
              "Montag - Dienstag...")
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/oVkbOW)**.

You might also want some more info about **[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You require whitespace between the times and the dashes: `\\s\\S*\\s`. Only the first occurance has such a whitespace. Try making that whitespace optional: `\\?\\S*\\s?`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String dates = "Mo 13:00 - 14:00, Di 15:00-19:00, Montag - Dienstag 18:00-23:00 Montag bis Samstag 03:00 bis 10:00";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?)((?<=\\d),?\\s(?=[A-Z])|$)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dates);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Output:

```
Mo 13:00 - 14:00
Di 15:00-19:00
Montag - Dienstag 18:00-23:00
Montag bis Samstag 03:00 bis 10:00
```